# What is $Z:=XY$ for random vector $(X,Y)$?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

The stochastic vector $(X,Y)$ has a continuous distribution with pdf:
$$f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
xe^{-x(y+1)}  & \text{if $x,y>0$} \\[2ex]
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
Define $Z:=XY$.
I would like to know what exactly $XY$ is. It seems to me that the function $f(x,y)$ has but one output, so what does $XY$ mean here? I feel like I'm missing something obvious. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ are two random variables. $Z$ is the multiplication of those two random variables, so $Z$ is just a different random variable. If you had a randomly chosen rectangle whose width and height were the random variables $X$ and $Y$, then $Z$ would be the area of that rectangle.

Comment: So if I find the marginals of the joint pdf, and multiply them, does that give me the pdf of $Z$? Or am I making some huge mistake here?

Comment: Huge mistake. To find the pdf of $Z$, first find the cdf of $Z$, which is $P(Z\le z)=P(XY\le z)$. To find $P(XY\le z)$, you have to integrate the joint pdf of $(X,Y)$ over the region where $xy\le z$, as in Surb's answer.

Comment: That makes sense, I'm not sure what I was thinking. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$\mathbb P\{Z\leq t\}=\iint_{\{(x,y)\mid xy\leq t\}}f_{(X,Y)}(u,v)dudv.$$

Comment: So does that mean the pdf is the same, but on a different domain?

Comment: Yes, but I'm unfortunately not sure that you totally understand why.

Comment: I think I do now, just didn't really really remember the properties of a joint pdf, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly clarifying some confusion. You are not telling us what is $X$ and what is $Y$. You are telling us their joint density $$\mathbb P[(X,Y)\in (dx,dy)]:=f_{(X,Y)}:=f: \mathbb R\times\mathbb R\to[0,\infty).$$
Quite fundamentally, a density has to have only one output. Knowing $Z:=XY$ means knowing its law, which is a consequence of knowing its density $f_{Z}$ (when it exists). As $X$ and $Y$ are real valued, $Z$ is real valued, so you should expect that $f_Z:\mathbb R\to [0,\infty)$. You can compute  $F_Z$ via the hint of Surb above (extra hint, you know what is $\mathbb E [\phi(X,Y)]$, then pick $\phi(x,y)=\mathbf 1_{xy\le t}$).

Comment: Yes, it seems like I just forgot about the concept of a joint pdf. Thanks for the clarification.